# Why is $\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-3}-2}{\sqrt{x^{2}+5}+2x}$ different from $\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x^{2}}}-\frac{2}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^{2}}}+2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Based on my understanding, $\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-3}-2}{\sqrt{x^{2}+5}+2x}$ is  $\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x^{2}}}-\frac{2}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^{2}}}+2}$ multiply by $\frac{x}{x}$, which is 1. However, when I tried to graph them, they are different when x is approaching negative infinity.

I have failed to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: You need dollar signs....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you !

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ not $x$.

Comment: You're using the fact that $\,x=\sqrt{x^2},\,$ but is that true as $\,x \to -\infty \,$?

Comment: Ah ! That makes sense !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5}}x=\sqrt{1+\frac5{x^2}}.$$
But that's not true when $x<0$. In that case,
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5}}x=-\sqrt{1+\frac5{x^2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is different for $x<0$ and moreover the second one is not defined for $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|, ~~~\sqrt{x^4}=x^2$$ So $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5}}{x}=\frac{|x|}{x} \sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}$$ So for $$x<0$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5}}{x}=- \sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}$$
and for $$x>0$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5}}{x}= + \sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}$$
and when $$x=0$$ you cannot divide by zero.